# Multiple Angular 10 components with same html template

Tags: angular, angular-components

Is it good practice to have multiple angular components with same html template. I have a use case in which same html template fulfill the purpose for 5 different components. There is 01 component specific heading which can be bind with property in `*.ts` file. Main difference is action (on click method) which will be performed differently in 05 components. I am very well aware of content projection but my use case is way to simple for it as there is mostly actions are component specific but html presentation is same.

I wrote a test angular app to test and this works as expected, *my question is if it has any downside of it and can it be count as standard practice?*

**base.component.html**

```
<!-- Base Component template which will be used by other component. It doesn't have *.ts file -->
<p>base works! from {{componentName}}</p>
<button (click)="print()">Print</button>
```

**sub-a.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Test } from '../test';

// This component does not have *.html and *.css file but will use shared *.html and *.css files.
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sub-a',
    templateUrl: '../base/base.component.html', // Base Component template
    styleUrls: ['../base/base.component.scss'] // Base Component template
})
export class SubAComponent implements OnInit, Test {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public componentName: string = 'SubAComponent';

    print(): void {
        console.log('Print from SubAComponent.');
    }
}
```

**sub-b.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Test } from '../test';

// This component does not have *.html and *.css file but will use shared *.html and *.css files.    
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sub-b',
    templateUrl: '../base/base.component.html', // Base Component template
    styleUrls: ['../base/base.component.scss'] // Base Component template
})
export class SubBComponent implements OnInit, Test {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    public componentName: string = 'SubBComponent';

    print(): void {
        console.log('Print from SubBComponent.');
    }
}
```

**test.ts**

```
import { basename } from "node:path"

// Method in this interface is used in "basename.component.html".
// So, all components sharing "basename.component.html" will implement this interface
export interface Test {
    print(): void;
}
```

Comment: If the difference is just the action button, then why not create one reusable component with an output() and then in the parent do whatever you want after the user clicked that button?

Comment: sorry late comment. I did the same and got it to prod. you can write this as solution I shall mark it correct :)